# what is the dpdk0's effect in ovs-dpdk?

Tags: openstack, dpdk, openvswitch

today i get other guy's confiuration about ovs-dpdk,the config file is below:

```
dpdk-devbind –s
dpdk-devbind --force --bind=ixgbe 0000:81:00.0
dpdk-devbind --force --bind=ixgbe 0000:81:00.1
dpdk-devbind --force --bind=igb_uio 0000:81:00.0
dpdk-devbind --force --bind=igb_uio 0000:81:00.1
ovs-vsctl del-port br-eth6 eth6
ovs-vsctl del-port br-eth9 eth9
ovs-vsctl  -- set Interface dpdk0 type=dpdk options:dpdk-devargs= 0000:06:00.0,n_rxq=1
ovs-vsctl  -- set Interface eth6 type=dpdk options:dpdk-devargs= 0000:81:00.0,n_rxq=1
ovs-vsctl  -- set Interface eth7 type=dpdk options:dpdk-devargs= 0000:81:00.1,n_rxq=1
```

the config file describe about take eth6 and eth9 ethernet interface to ovs bridge br-eth6 and br-eth9 but i wonder to know why set interface dpdk0's type to dpdk ? Does the port dpdk0 is a specific port or something else?
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: i think there is a mistake in this file,the last line eth7 shoud be eth9

Comment: very confusing configuration. `ovs-vsctl del-port ` should be invoked first. Because as soon as one  remove the bnd from `ixgbe` there kernel netlink interface `eth6` and `eth9` is longer present. It bound to dpdk `igb_uio`. Can you clean up your question? I am holding off not to mark this `needs improvement` as it may have some potential.

Comment: @VipinVarghese thank you for the answer.i understand you think the sequence of the configuration is wrong? We must delete the port from ovs first and then we can bind the dpdk port successfully.i will delete the part of the question.but i want to know what the effect of the dpdk0 port?

Comment: please update the question you have shared to reflect the intention. As of now there are multiple questions like `1. wonder to know why set interface dpdk0's type to dpdk ?, 2. Does the port dpdk0 is a specific port or something else?`. If the question is about ovs-dpdk share the version, share your setup where you confused or stuck? share if you have tried changing from `dpdk0` to `mydpdk0` (you will figure out why naming format is important).

Comment: i asked the guy who give me the configration,the file is not the whole file.i want to test the network performance of openstack,when install openstack with dpdk,dpdk0 is the default port of the environment.and I make a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments discussion, the problem turned out to be the configuration file sequence. Recommend approach of removing the Kernel Ports, then binding with dpdk compatible driver works

```
ovs-vsctl del-port br-eth6 eth6
ovs-vsctl del-port br-eth9 eth9
dpdk-devbind –s
dpdk-devbind --force --bind=ixgbe 0000:81:00.0
dpdk-devbind --force --bind=ixgbe 0000:81:00.1
dpdk-devbind --force --bind=igb_uio 0000:81:00.0
dpdk-devbind --force --bind=igb_uio 0000:81:00.1
ovs-vsctl  -- set Interface dpdk0 type=dpdk options:dpdk-devargs= 0000:06:00.0,n_rxq=1
ovs-vsctl  -- set Interface eth6 type=dpdk options:dpdk-devargs= 0000:81:00.0,n_rxq=1
ovs-vsctl  -- set Interface eth7 type=dpdk options:dpdk-devargs= 0000:81:00.1,n_rxq=1
```